# GraphQL Move a child property into parent

Tags: graphql

I'm looking into GraphQL and got to a question I'm not even sure how to look for in the docs. Probably this isn't even supposed to work, but I'll ask anyway.

I have this query:

```
query {
  organization(login: "facebook") {
    repositories(first: 5) {
      items: edges {
        repo: node {
          name
          owner {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the response I would like a way to place the login next to name, instead of nested in owner login.

So in the response instead of:

```
{
  ...
  "name": "react-native",
  "owner": {
     "login": "facebook"
  }
}
```

I would like to have:

```
{
...
"name": "react-native",
"ownerName": "facebook"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the specification this is not possible. The response has to be shaped in the way the object types are shaped. There is a project called [GraphQL Lodash](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash) that gives you a new directive to modify the results. It can be helpful here but it is rather experimental and IMO very undogmatic.